# Unexpected field error from Multer while file uploading

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

Hi I want to create a file upload API with react and express. So, I used muster. But when I send to axis request from client I get an error from server.

Error:

> MulterError: Unexpected field

my Express server code snipped like that:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination : '/',
    filename(req,file,cb){
        const newFileName = `${uuid()}-${file.originalname}`
        cb(null,newFileName);
    }
})

const uploadVideoFile = multer({
    storage : storage
}).single("videofile");

app.post('/upload', uploadVideoFile, (req,res)=>{
    if(req.file){
        const filename = req.file.filename;
        const {title , description} = req.body;

        open(oAuth.generateAuthUrl({
            access_type : 'offline',
            scope : 'https://googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
            state : JSON.stringify({
                filename, title, description
            })
        }))
    }
})
```

And my react client like that:

```
    const[form,setForm] = React.useState({
        title : "",
        description : "",
        file : null
    })

    function handleChange(event){
        const inputValue = event.target.name === "file" ? event.target.files[0] : event.target.value;

        setForm({
            ...form,
            [event.target.name] : inputValue
        })
    }

    function handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        
        const videoData = new FormData();
        videoData.append("videoFile", form.file);
        videoData.append("title", form.title);
        videoData.append("description", form.description);

        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/upload', videoData).then(response=>{
            console.log(response.data)
        })
    }

    return (
    <div>
        <h1>Youtube Upload Service</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div>
                <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" name="title" autoComplete="off" placeholder="Title"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <textarea onChange={handleChange} type="text" name="description" autoComplete="off" placeholder="Description"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input onChange={handleChange} accept="video/mp4" type="file" name="file" placeholder="Video File"/>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Upload Video</button>
        </form>
    </div>
        )
}
```

Why I'm getting this error? How can I solve this?

Comment: This may be due to the mismatch in case - the f of `videofile` is uppercase on the client, but lowercase on the server.

Answer (score 2):

When Multer sees a file it checks whether the name of the file input matches *exactly* what you've configured. It's also case sensitive.

You've configured Multer to accept a single file input named "videofile": `.single("videofile")`. In the frontend however, you're naming it "videoFile" (with capital F): `videoData.append("videoFile", form.file);`. Since "videofile" !== "videoFile", Multer throws an unexpected field error.

Renaming either of the two to match the other should fix your issue. To understand how Multer works and how you can avoid this error in the future, I recommend reading this article: [Fix "Unexpected field" Error From Multer](https://maximorlov.com/fix-unexpected-field-error-multer/)